# Python: TypeError: Can't convert 'generator' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, string, generator, typeerror

I'm doing an assignment and here is what the class looks like:

```
class GameStateNode:
    '''
    A tree of possible states for a two-player, sequential move, zero-sum,
    perfect-information game.

    value: GameState -- the game state at the root of this tree
    children: list -- all possible game states that can be reached from this
    game state via one legal move in the game.  children is None until grow
    is called.
    '''

    def __init__(self, game_state):
        ''' (GameStateNode, GameState) -> NoneType

        Initialize a new game state tree consisting of a single root node 
        that contains game_state.
        '''
        self.value = game_state
        self.children = []
```

I then wrote these two functions in because I need a recursive str:

```
    def __str__(self):
        ''' (GameStateNode) -> str '''    
        return _str(self)

def _str(node):
    ''' (GameStateNode, str) -> str '''
    return ((str(node.value) + '\n') + 
            ((str(child) for child in node.children) if node.children else ''))
```

Can somebody tell me what the problem is with my _str function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the part where you iterate over the children and convert them to strings:

```
(str(child) for child in node.children)
```

That is actually a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), which can't be simply converted to a string and concatenated with the left part `str(node.value) + '\n'`.

Before doing the string concatenation, you should probably join the strings that get created by the generator into a single string by calling `join`. Something like this will join the strings using a comma:

```
','.join(str(child) for child in node.children)
```

In the end, your code should probably be simplified to something like

```
def _str(node):
    ''' (GameStateNode, str) -> str '''
    return (str(node.value) + '\n' + 
        (','.join(str(child) for child in node.children) if node.children else ''))
```

Of course, you can join the strings with some other character or string, like '\n', if you want to.

Comment: Works! Thanks a million!