# Rename every csv file in every subfolder according to its parent-subfoldername

Tags: python

I have an issue in a relatively simple script, but the error that is showing up is something new for me:

The goal is as follows:
I have a parentfolder (test), which contains about 700 subfolders (test 1 - test 700)
In those subfolders different files are stored, but I'm only interested in the .csv file, of which there is only one per subfolder. Unforuntately, this csv file is generated via another program and thus it gets a whacky name.

I want to change the names of all csvs in all the subfolders to the name of their parent-subfolder:

```
import os 


directoryPath=r"C:\...\test"
os.chdir(directoryPath)
folder_list=os.listdir(directoryPath)
subfolder_list=os.walk(directoryPath)
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):
    for name in file:
        if name.endswith(".csv"):
            os.rename(name, subfolder_list)
        else:
            pass
```

Unfortunately I'm getting following error:

TypeError: rename: dst should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not generator

I read up about this error ( [Python: TypeError: Can't convert 'generator' object to str implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426766/python-typeerror-cant-convert-generator-object-to-str-implicitly/29426865) ) but I'm not sure I understand the solution.

Does someone have an easier approach to solve this?

Greetings and thank you

Comment: In `os.rename(name, subfolder_list)`, `subfolder_list` is the result of your call to `s.walk(directoryPath)` - which is not a string, bytes or os.Pathlike, but a generator.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. Curious why I didn't find that question while looking for it - yeah it does solve it!